# Print values instead of hashcode for a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, tostring, hashcode, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to output all the key value pairs in a ConcurrentHashMap. I realized that my problem is that the key is a Character [], so when I do the following code:

```
for (Entry<Character [], Integer> e : wordCountMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue());
}
```

I get back results like this: [Ljava.lang.Character;@51de8adb=527

I think the default toString method of Character[] is printing the hashcode. How can I display the value of the Character array (meaning, the values of each character in order)? Normally I'd override the toString method, but Character isn't a class I made myself, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString()` or use a for loop yourself.

Comment: Arrays.toString(e.getKey());
Like that?

Comment: Must be a ruby programmer:  First thing he wants to do is monkey patch.

Comment: Why at all you use `Character[]` as the key, not `String`?
Using arrays as HashMap keys is generally a bad idea, since you can't override their `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. So arrays are always compared by reference, not by the actual contents.